# Will any DVD drive work with Ubuntu?

Tags: dvd

I have scourged websites for Samsung / Lite-on/ LG / Asus and none list "Linux" in their OS Supported sections.

Is there a special brand / model of dvd drive for Ubuntu / Linux? Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to define "work". Most retail consumer DVD drives will read disks just fine in Linux. It gets a bit more complicated (but not much anymore) when your trying to burn a DVD. Playing a DVD (movie) can be a nightmare to a first computer user regardless of OS. I don't know of any "LightScribe" burners that will "print" on the disks in Linux.

Comment: I just need to be able to use it to: 1) load Ubuntu, 2) load other programs, 3) transfer data (read/write). You mention (at the bottom) there are plenty of drives that don't work. Is there a short list of brnds/models that you would avoid? With the answers provided I am leaning towards just purchasing an LG sata dvd drive.

Comment: Th LG drive should work fine, retail drives should work fine.

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/ could help you as well (though it's more for complete system)

Comment: I appreciate your time. Thank you & everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, most dvd drives use a standard method of communicating with the OS. They have to, too, because everyone expects to be able to boot from them from within the BIOS, which is very bare-bones. The only issue you might run into is *playing* dvds.

That requires some legally questionable libdvdcss stuff, or a $20 player from the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Answer (score 0):

Generally should every DVD drive work with Ubuntu.

I don't know why it should not and never saw one, that didn't worked with Ubuntu, too.

Comment: You have not been exposed to much hardware, there are plenty of DVD drives that will not work in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Virtually any major brand DVD drive would work.  Samsung, Lite-on, LG, Asus, HP, Sony, and Plextor.  SATA or IDE interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should work. If the site doesn't show Linux as supported OS, it doesn't mean that it will not support.

In my desktop, I'm using `LG DVD/RW Drive`, and in my laptop it is Samsungs' DVD Drive. My friends are using HP, Sony, Dell and others laptops with different DVD/RW drives and they never faced any trouble using with Ubuntu.

In short yes it should support without any problem...